# Can you invoke several methods on an object at once?

Tags: java, c++, oop, syntax

Just a little question i had trouble googling the answer too.

Is it possible to do something like..

```
bomb.setX(newx)
     .setY(newy);
```

bomb is just an object with methods setX and setY, i was just wondering if you could string method invocations together somehow to save space and make things more human readable? I'm sure i've seen something similar before..

Oh cruicially i'm working in java here. Though I would be interested to know if such a shorthand exists in c++ too if anyone knows :)

Comment: Great answers thank you folks, i understand what's going on much better now. So is returning an object in simple setter methods worth doing for this kind of use or a bit wasteful? or perhaps the difference is negligible ?

Comment: The difference amounts to pusing this onto the stack, but this had to be done anyway if you call a second method. So the only "waste" is that the object reference will have to be popped off the stack after the last call.

Comment: Yes as the answers below indicate, *but* the methods are executed right to left one after each other. They do *not* execute 'at once' or in parallel. It's basically syntax-sugar to save typing 'bomb.' again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `setX` returns the bomb, yes.

```
public Bomb setX(Object x){
    this.x = x;
    return this;
}
```

Call this **fluent interface**. To achieve this fluent interface it is using a technique called **method chaining**.

*In software engineering, a fluent interface (as first coined by Eric Evans and Martin Fowler) is an implementation of an object oriented API that aims to provide for more readable code.
A fluent interface is normally implemented by using method chaining to relay the instruction context of a subsequent call (but a fluent interface entails more than just method chaining).* [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a matter of invoking several methods at the same time, but of doing method chaining.

Typically, it is possible because these methods return `this`:

```
// class X
public X setX(int val)
{
    x = val;
    return this;
}
```

etc etc.

Comment: as above: please not that it won't be a JavaBean "setter" any more.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make this syntax work, `setX` must return the object on which it operates. This is reasonably common. In C++ you return a reference to itself - see C++ streams for an example.

```
Bomb& Bomb::setX(X& newX) {
    x = newX;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you are talking about chaining invocation (when all void methods returns this). This feature is proposed to be in Java 7, but rejected I far as I know. So, there is no build-in mechanism for chaining invocation in java today. Look at [Builder design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), it's very close but designed for readonly classes.

Also, you can always implement [Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, but in order to do that every setter will need to return `this`, which is not too good for setters, as frameworks will not be able to find those any more. For example, the standard `java.beans.Introspector` ignores non-`void` setters:

```
public class Chain {
    private int i;

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public Chain setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IntrospectionException {
        PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Chain.class).getPropertyDescriptors();
        for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : propertyDescriptors) {
            System.out.println("property = " + propertyDescriptor.getDisplayName());
            System.out.println("read = " + propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod());
            System.out.println("write = " + propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod());
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
property = class
read = public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()
write = null
property = i
read = public int org.acm.afilippov.Chain.getI()
write = null
```

Given that Apache BeanUtils uses it, chances are that many of Apache frameworks will decide that the property is readonly.

Comment: "frameworks will not be able to find those anymore", what do you mean

Comment: @Raynos well, setters in Java are used extensively by frameworks; and usually a setter is a method returning `void`. Returning anything else may well mean that frameworks will ignore the property. So a good practice would be, not call the methods to be chained `setXxxx`.

Comment: If the framework if done properly, then a proper getter/setter name and parameter list should be enough. Don't see why it should look at the return type while invoking it via reflection except for being 100% pure (i.e. setters MUST return void).

Comment: @alf why do frameworks ignore properties that do not return `void` ? That just sounds like bad frameworks do bad stuff.

Comment: @Zenzen see the update for an actual case where frameworks fail to recognise the setter

Comment: @Raynos it's the spec, and the reference `java.beans.Introspector`—bad or not, that's exactly what's specified and what happens.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info, i actually hadn't heard of java beans yet and don't know much about frameworks but this is good to know and i will do some further reading on them thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

More ore less yes.

It will work if Bomb.setX() return its own instance.

```
class Bomb{

    ...

   Bomb setX(int value) {
      this.x = value;
      return this;
   }

}
```

The complete topic is called [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

But unfortunaly the most Java Libs, and as far as I know, the complate java core, do not follow this idea. And the more worst thing is, that the Java-Bean Specification (the thing that define the relationship beween variable, getter and setter) is not based on this prinicip. So if you have an Framework that needs Java-Beans then it may or may not work with classes like that.

Answer (score 1):

Well if the methods are correctly defined - then yes! Actually what you are looking for is a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). The main objective of a fluent interface is method chaining. For instance [builders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) are oftend implemented in that way and you get:

```
new SomethingBuilder().withX(x).withY(y).build();
```

You just need to return (for instance) "this" in setX and setY.

Answer (score 0):

You can, if setX and setY return the bomb object.  This allows you to chain methods and this is referred to as the [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).  You can have a look at an example in Java here:

http://hilloldebnath.byethost3.com/2009/08/20/implementing-the-fluent-interface-approach-in-java/